# Launch an EXE from binary file

Tags: wix

Hi I have these two binary files:

```
<Binary Id="Sentinel" SourceFile="sentinel_setup.exe"/>
<Binary Id="Hasp" SourceFile="HASPUserSetup.exe"/>
```

And I would like to start them on a button click like so:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchHasp" BinaryKey="Hasp" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncWait" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchSentinel" BinaryKey="Sentinel" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncWait"/>

<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchHasp">1</Publish>
```

But it doesn't work, It only works when I run the installer from the command line with elevated privileges. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Or can someone tell me how I could extract the file from the binary table using a c++ custom action as I cannot get it working at all..:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Immediate custom actions doesn't have elevated privileges.** You should use **deffered custom actions** for such needs. Any action that make changes to the destimation environment should be deffered. For more details read this article: http://bonemanblog.blogspot.com/2005/10/custom-action-tutorial-part-i-custom.html

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchHasp" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="Hasp" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncWait" />
```

Though deffered custom actions are executed during installation phase, not on button click. Revise your installer logic. As I understand, your exe file "sentinel_setup.exe" changes the system, so should be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize events in [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372038%28v=vs.85%29)

I would recommend adding a checkbox, that user should mark to install your "Hasp" (or installer Feature which user should select in the feature tree). And add deffered custom action with condition on this checkbox state.

Sometimes it is really required to launch admin actions during or before installer UI sequence. In this case you need to create a setup bootstrapper which asks for permission elevation and does required actions before running MSI process. To ask for permissions you need to add application manifest to your bootstrapper project. My bootstrapper is quite simple, but works in many cases. It is Windows application (though without any Windows forms - it allows to hide console window) which contains only icon, application manifest and small code file:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SetupBootstrapper
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var currentDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var parameters = string.Empty;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var arg in args)
                {
                    if (arg != "/i" && arg != "/x" && arg != "/u")
                    {
                        sb.Append(" ");
                        sb.Append(arg);
                    }
                }
                parameters = sb.ToString();
            }

            bool isUninstall = args.Contains("/x") || args.Contains("/u");

            string msiPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, "MyMsiName.msi");

            if(!File.Exists(msiPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File '{0}' doesn't exist", msiPath), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            string installerParameters = (isUninstall ? "/x" : "/i ") + "\"" + msiPath + "\"" + parameters;

            var installerProcess = new Process { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec", installerParameters) { Verb = "runas" } };

            installerProcess.Start();
            installerProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my post. Added info about bootstrapper application. As for your idea with extracting the exe file from custom action - it is overcomplicated and I'm sure it will not work because of the same security restrictions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, does this bootstrapper only show my MSI dialogs? Thanks so much

Comment: No, it execute your MSI exactly as you are doing it from command line with admin provileges. So you can specify whether to show UI or use silent mode (/qn argument) and any other functionality that is present in MSI still there. Provided Bootstrapper only runs MSI with admin privileges - nothing else.

Comment: That is brilliant, Do I use the Windows Form Application in visual studio then? Sorry probably a silly question but i'm still relatively new to all of this..:)

Comment: Create Windows Application project, remove a form from it - you don't need it. Replace the Program.cs with what I posted. Add new project item > Application manifest (special xml file type). Edit it to <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireadministrator">. That's all basically =). Place the bootstrapper in the same folder as MSI and run.

Comment: That's awesome, really thank you so much. I would have to ship the two files together would i?

Comment: Yes, you should. And always use the bootstrapper instead of MSI. THe only exception is running from admin console (may be needed for group policy delivery for example. But that's advanced admin scenario)